# How to replace jQuery change and val methods with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-selectors, dom-events

Shopping cart contains jQuery code to attach event handler and set values in external widget:

```
$(function () { 
  $("#smartpost_select0" ).change(function() {
    var valik = $('#smartpost_select0').val();
    $('.js-transportselect-radio').prop("checked", false);
    if (valik==='-') {
      $('#Field1').val('');
      } else {
      $('#Field1').val('SMARTPOST'+valik);
      $('#Field2').val('SMARTPOST');

   };
    
  });

  });
```

`smartpost_select0` is created by external widget by external Javascript file.
`Field1` and `Field2` are input type=text fields created by application. `.js-transportselect-radio` class and fields are created by application.

How to change this code to remove jQuery dependency? Are there native methods to attach change handler and toggle checked property?

Comment: `$('#smartpost_select0').val()` to `document.querySelector('#smartpost_select0').value` `$('#Field2').val('SMARTPOST')` to `document.querySelector('#Field2').value = 'SMARTPOST'`
`$('..').change(function(){...})` to `document.querySelector('...').addEventListener('change', function(){...})`
`$('...').prop(key, value)` to `document.querySelector('...').setAttribute(key, value)`

Comment: How to replace change and prop methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addEventListener()` is the native equivalent of `on()`. `checked` and `value` are properties of the Element objects, so don't require a method such as jQuery's `attr()` or `prop()`. Similarly, `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` allow you to retrieve DOM elements using CSS-style selectors.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let field1 = document.querySelector('#Field1');
  let field2 = document.querySelector('#Field2');

  document.querySelector('#smartpost_select0').addEventListener('change', e => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.js-transportselect-radio').forEach(el => el.checked = false);
    
    let valik = e.target.value;
    if (valik === '-') {
      field1.value = '';
    } else {
      field1.value = 'SMARTPOST' + valik;
      field2.value = 'SMARTPOST';
    }
  });
});
```

For future reference, the site http://youmightnotneedjquery.com has a helpful reference for converting jQuery methods to native JS.

Comment: Why`DOMContentLoad` also worked? It is undefined event.

Comment: I'm not sure, as it was a typo on my part - there is no `DOMContentLoad` event.